# Why were these answers deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

I recently saw somebody attempt to answer the question [Strange ARC issue not releasing ivar in UIView subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989218/strange-arc-issue-not-releasing-ivar-in-uiview-subclass).  He posted the same answer twice: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180312/8427) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12019215/8427).  Both times, his answer - which as far as I can see is correct, offers a workaround, and links to the official documentation describing the bug in question - was deleted by two different diamond moderators and cannot be undeleted.

If two separate diamond moderators both thought that the answers should be deleted, I'm assuming this wasn't an accident, but I can't see what the problem is with the answers, and I can't see any way of finding out short of a meta post.

Comment: It's worth noting that the first time the answer was deleted on Aug 18, it only had a brief paragraph with a link to the user's blog. Someone may have assumed it was spam? Then the user appears to have edited their original post today (Aug 29) while it was already deleted. Finding that he couldn't undelete the post, he presumably created another copy of his answer (within a minute of the original edit). I can imagine that this would auto-flag the answer as a problem, since it's an exact duplicate of an existing answer. Perhaps a moderator figured if the original answer was bad, this was too.

Comment: @dmckee, one was deleted by Bill The Lizard, the other by Brad Larson. You're looking at Eugene's answer.

Comment: The second delete is likely to have come from the 'exact duplicate' flag that gets auto-raised. Flagging and requesting undelete is the expected behaviour, not simply reposting.

Comment: Er...how did I misunderstand that. I looked at it. I swear I did. ANyway. Deleting the incorrect comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you note, I was one of those who deleted that answer there. I also deleted the same answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857518/arc-with-zombies-why-do-objects-in-instance-variables-not-get-released-when-ow), and removed some other answers there that just pointed to a duplicate question. As Robert states, these were all copied and pasted from [this original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408071/why-is-object-not-dealloced-when-using-arc-nszombieenabled/12019155#12019155).

The original answer is a good one (sitting at five upvotes right now, one of them mine), and it's on a canonical question for this topic. The fact that he could copy and paste the same answer to multiple questions was a red flag that these were all the same issue, and sure enough they were. I therefore closed the other two questions as duplicates of the central one.

Nothing was lost here, and this prevents solutions from being scattered around the place for people searching about this issue. In cases like this, we recommend flagging questions as duplicates rather than pasting the same answer across multiple ones.

Answer (score 12):

They were deleted because the user was copy/pasting his answer on multiple duplicates of the same question, and it was flagged by the system as "Identical Posts."

The single, remaining instance of the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12019155/102937.  The other questions on which this answer was posted are now closed as duplicates.

Comment: The [original](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12019155/1) [versions](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12019215/1) were barely any more than a few links too.